# Find largest files in a directory in a specific date range

Tags: linux, find

I'm looking for a UNIX command or set of commands, by which I can find the 20 largest files in a directory, based on a specific date range.

To do this I thought I could set the date range by touching a couple of files and then doing a find based on those file dates.  i.e.

```
touch /tmp/point.start -d "2018-06-01 00:00"
touch /tmp/point.end -d "2018-06-30 00:00"
```

and then run

```
find . -newer /tmp/point.start ! -newer /tmp/point.end
```

And to get the lagest 20 files I intended to run, from the directory,

```
ls -ltr | sort -nk5 | tail -20
```

But what I can't seem to do is combine the two

```
find . -newer /tmp/point.start ! -newer /tmp/point.end | ls -ltr | sort -nk5 | tail -20
```

simply ignores the first part and lists the 20 largest files in the directory regardless of size. I'm sure it's something very obvious I'm missing, but I can't figure out what!

(I'm on RedHat 5.3, and don't have access to newermt)

Comment: Not having RHEL 5.3 around, does your `find` have a `-printf` option?

Comment: you could try to run a `-exec` instead of piping.

Comment: @Jeff, GNU `find` has had `-printf` since before Linux let alone RedHat even existed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
find . -newer /tmp/point.start ! -newer /tmp/point.end  ! -path . | xargs ls -ltr | sort -nk5 | tail -20
```

- `xargs`  build and execute command lines from standard input

Comment: worked perfectly.  Now my next question is how do I accept this answer? :)

Comment: no need to pass to xargs just to do an ls -- `find ... -ls` will do it; just requires you to adjust the sort field

Comment: `find . -newer /tmp/point.start ! -newer /tmp/point.end -ls|sort -k7n`

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yes, but i too struck like you with RHEL5.

Comment: this assumes that none of your usernames or group names contain spaces, of course

Comment: Does that version of `find` not have an `-ls` option?

Comment: @JeffSchaller should be `find: paths must precede expression: ls`

Comment: Thanks folks.  Both Jeff and Siva had working answers, but I've accepted the latter since that's the one I used.  Is that correct etiquette on StackExchange?

Comment: I would just point out the additional risk with the existing answer that if any files or directories have spaces in their names, pipe that to xargs will break.  `mkdir "a directory" and touch a file in there with a relevant timestamp to see.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I second it.

Comment: @JeffSchaller, it's not only spaces, it's also newlines, quotes, backslashes and some other whitespace characters the list of  which depends on the xargs implementations. Some `xargs` implementations also choke on bytes not forming valid characters. Generally, you can't pipe find to xargs unless you use the `-print0`/`-r0` GNU extensions. But even then it's unnecessary as `find` supports `-exec cmd {} +`.

Answer (score 3):

If you can use `-printf` with your `find`:

```
find . -newer /tmp/point.start ! -newer /tmp/point.end -printf '%s %p\n' | 
  sort -rn | head -20
```

Comment: If you want to find the top 20 file by disk occupation and not by file size, you can use `%b %p\n` instead of `%s %p\n`

Comment: `find . -type f -newer /tmp/point.start ! -newer /tmp/point.end -printf '%s %p\0'|sort -zrn|xargs -0  printf '%s\n'|head -20` would be a slight improvement, though aptly-named files still break `head`

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload age # best in ~/.zshrc if you use that often
ls -ldS -- *(De:age 2018-06-01 2018-06-30:OL[1,20])
```

- `-S`: sort by size. With GNU `ls` (as found on RedHat 5.3), you can use `-U` for not sorting as `zsh` has sorted the list already with `OL`.
- `(...)`: glob qualifier
- `D`: don't ignore dot files.
- `e:code:` evaluate the code to decide whether to select the file
- `age date1 date2`: returns true for files with mtime in that range (without time part, it defaults to 00:00:00)
- `OL`: reverse sort by length (size)
- `[1,20]`: only select the first 20 ones.